# Paypal IPN working but returns error status 500

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having trouble with Paypal IPN. I'm using the IPN script from github:
[Script link](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

This is the php code for the script:

```
    <?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 0);


define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}

?>
```

...with my post-processing code being after the verifiy check

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

When someone pays via Paypal, everything seems to work in terms of my site receiving the IPN data and processing it. However, when I check the IPN logs in Paypal it has a status code of 500 (internal server error) and keeps resending the IPN data.

I have no idea why this is happening. This same IPN script (or close variations) are all over the net so I presume the script is fine.

Here is the log file recorded by the script:

```
[2015-08-15 13:31 Europe/London] HTTP request of validation request:POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
Host: www.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 1014
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 for IPN payload: cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=4.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=unconfirmed&payer_id=--------&tax=0.00&address_street=------&payment_date=05%3A25%3A51+Aug+15%2C+2015+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=------&first_name=-----&mc_fee=0.27&address_country_code=ES&address_name=-----&notify_version=3.8&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=--------&address_country=Spain&address_city=-------&quantity=1&verify_sign=AEWexEu2HAXvtIxtV.FjJ4XDJIdfA8MGuWBu9unU4dGBd7qVw2YL2a0p&payer_email=--------&txn_id=-------&payment_type=instant&payer_business_name=------&last_name=W----&address_state=------&receiver_email=--------&payment_fee=&receiver_id=-------&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=---------&mc_currency=GBP&item_number=------&residence_country=GB&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=--------
[2015-08-15 13:31 Europe/London] HTTP response of validation request: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Paypal-Debug-Id: 85e8fa12ae5b4
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DC: slc-origin-www.paypal.com
Date: Sat, 15 Aug 2015 12:31:22 GMT
Content-Length: 8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=GsUqRUQy6PV-FIg6NZNaoWTmld6up9P1KKqndXexz_jj_zeAZ4x0Kn30L4uIpy__dU4bnuACyaC89S34gzVIGmA2RmA8EBSoiH6oFumGT1YG-PxlbiMrDzyyNIjAnfFEJ0XPZmwovk7hutZlJannbvBOGibCAawKZ3rpqkphLxNrDZR-AZa0OAwjsUNEJtcy8gxroi8dbImfynYwQxhP_tTP1422-p2gLl8hxdhVqzO1PgDbCALd3kqfM67UCXZ0TVNpr5Pi84KsVZkZ1X00PblzKmbsFJ8vS7wbmocXEJveA6o1mPllq-qKO9MOEppBM0IxMS8rbwafRFDBzkFepW_gsNCkQPAATYNkLS6PTiBYMzL5-VV4ku_b4xTAsT_q4cotE5q4d-hqH1sE4fkdbql8HGCNwIiq2RpYrsI00nmMDrkGmZbHMV02BMG; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Tue, 12-Aug-2025 12:31:22 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Mon, 14-Aug-2017 12:31:22 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.16.0.147.1439641881720232; path=/; expires=Mon, 07-Aug-45 12:31:21 GMT
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE9.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D422694741; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.16.0.206.1439641881713999; path=/; expires=Mon, 07-Aug-45 12:31:21 GMT
Set-Cookie: AKDC=slc-origin-www.paypal.com; expires=Sat, 15-Aug-2015 13:01:22 GMT; path=/; secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

VERIFIED
```

Does anyone know why I could be getting this 500 error?

I've searched the net for a solution but can't find out what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Follow these [steps for testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you should be able to find your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that my php script was throwing an error that I didn't notice causing the ipn handler to not return HTTP 200 code. Sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a "/" at the end of the url.

Example:

The URL http:///paypal/notify gives the error status 500 but the URL http:///paypal/notify/ works fine.